# Erase zimbra emails via mySQL?

Tags: mysql, zimbra

I am running Zimbra Mail Server ZCS 7.2.7 on a linux server.
I would like to run a scheduled task every week that erases all emails with a specific subject.

I have learned that zimbra uses mySQL to store its emails.

So I'm wondering...can I run a Delete statement to mySQL and erase the emails this way?

Any disadvantage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zimbra most certainly expects a certain database scheme (tables and attribute values). Some can be enforced by SQL, others not. The chances that deleting records from the database will mess up the Zimbra installation is extremely high. You should only manipulate the database externally after understanding the internal storage format of Zimbra.